# Xcode rebuild on changes`

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I make Xcode automatically build when I save changes to a file?

I may have to stop developing for apple if I need to hit that stupid play button/ reach for a mouse one more time.
I am so desperate that I have even considered using Java.robots to click the screen for me on git commits

Comment: You mean hitting the build button? (cmd+b by default)

Comment: ahh yes you have definitely made the problem less bad! Is there a way though to automate that? I often use various watcher scripts to build to devices and deploy live. My usual work flow is to just check running versions of things. With this command key though I still need to stop thinking and run something b4 I can get back to writing code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I fully grasp what it is you're trying to accomplish.  You want Xcode to automatically build when you save changes to a file?

Comment: @DanF I think that James thought he had to build + run rather than just being able to build. Other IDEs like Visual Studio and Eclipse have  continual building in the background, something Xcode lacks.

Comment: Instead of saving the changes, I always do "command" + "R" which always saves the changes, builds and runs the app.

Comment: I am actually working on a Linux machine and have it set up on my git hooks to deploy all over the place. I am trying to integrate xcode into my personal automatic build process. Currently when I commit to my build branch it copies down all my files to xcode and after I build it copies that deployable back to my server but I have to stop to hit the build button.

Comment: Ok that is a lot more complicated of a situation than I first understood.  I really don't know how to solve that situation

Comment: ty for your input it helped me ask my question more clearly. I did ask it in an unclear manner.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Jenkins - This does exactly what you want. It's a bit of a faff to get it set up the first time, but it will save you hours in the long term.

Comment: Thats a hell of a lot of fluff to get one button to fire! Tell me do know where in that gagillion lines of code =) I could find the part I need?

Comment: You could look at something like this: http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/23/ci-with-jenkins-for-ios-apps-build-distribution-via-testflightapp-tutorial/ or http://idevstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/ios-continuous-integration-part-iv.html

Answer (score 2):

You can build without running by hitting (CMD+B) by default.  The default behavior of the IDE is to save modified files upon build, so if you just want to save and build all the time, just hit build, and it will do both for you.

You can even modify the shortcut key for build to be cmd+s if you really want to by opening up XCode preferences (Cmd+, by default, or going to the "XCode" menu in the top left and selecting preferences), and go to the keybindings section and change the "Build" action keybinding to be cmd+s